# SAS variable as SQL table name

Tags: sql, macros, sas, identifier, multipart

EDIT: Thank you for the quick responses. I have a lot to learn about SaS obviously but everyone's responses were very helpful.

Beginner here, trying to write SAS code that can be easily ported across systems.

Goal:
I want to have PROC SQL use a global variable for a multipart table identifier.

```
/* global variables*/
%LET lib_name="Merge_Contacts"
%LET table_name="Contacts"


/* Simple Query */
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE Merged_Contacts AS
        SELECT a.*, b.*
        /* Below is the problem area */
        /* SAS doesn't recognize this as a valid lib/table name */
        FROM &lib_name.&table_name 
        ... 
        /*merge another table*/
QUIT;
```

I've tried to concatenate this identifier in several ways to no success. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you add the quotes? You need to double up the period since the first will be used to indicate the end of the macro variable name, so you need another to be the delimiter between the libname and the member name. Also a LIBNAME cannot contain more than 8 characters.

Comment: @Tom, admittedly those coming from other programming languages cannot understand assigning values to variables without quotes. Maybe not all but most general-purpose (Python, C#, Java, VB) to special-purpose languages (R, SQL, XSLT) all require quotes when assigning values else compiler assumes the values are declared variables or objects themselves! So you can understand the OP's overlook (especially being new to SAS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* global variables*/
%LET lib_name=Mrg_ctat;  /* lib names 8 characters and you needed ; on
%LET table_name=Contacts;   both %let statements Also, remove "" */


/* Simple Query */
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE Merged_Contacts AS
        SELECT a.*, b.*
        /* Below is the problem area */
        /* SAS doesn't recognize this as a valid lib/table name */

       /* use .. to tag end of first macro variable. This will provide
          single . as separator */
        FROM &lib_name..&table_name 
        ... 
        /*merge another table*/
QUIT;
```

Comment: Posting just a code snippet is not a good answer.  You are likely to get more upvotes if you also post a sentence to go along with the code to explain what the problem was and what you did to fix it.

Comment: Also... why the double `&` in front of the libname.  A single `&` will suffice here.

Comment: either & or && will work. previous comment explains what was wrong

Comment: Sure && will work, but that's like saying `x + 1 - 2 + 1 + 4` is a good substitute for `x + 4`.  Nobody wants to read extra chars or figure out why they're included, or even worse, think that they're necessary in order for it to work.

Comment: some times you have something like &x&y and in order to resolve you use &&x&y.  I found this very confusing at first and found that whenever I see &var1 and &var2 being combined in some way  I use the &&.  so your example is not quite fair (imo)

Comment: Nope.  &&x&y will give a very different result to &x&y.  Here's an example: `%let x = a;  %let y = 1;  %let x1 = hello;  %let a1 = goodbye; 
 %put &x&y;  %put &&x&y;  %put &&&x&y;`  The macro language is hard enough without adding even more `&`s =P

Answer (score 1):

SAS does not have global variables, but you can create global MACRO variables. The SAS macro processor is a way to generate code.  You do not want to include the quote characters.  To the macro processor everything is a string so there is no need to add quotes to help it distinguish between a string and an operator or a variable name.  The macro triggers (% and &) are what allow the macro processor to know that something is to be considered for special processing before it is forwarded to the SAS language compiler.

Your `%LET` statements also need ending semi-colons to mark the end of the statement. End of line has no special meaning to the macro processor or to SAS code.

Also a SAS libref cannot have more than 8 characters.

```
/* global MACRO variables*/
%LET lib_name=source ;
%LET table_name=Contacts ;
```

If the LIBREF you are using is not already defined then you probably will also need to add a `LIBNAME` statement.

```
 libname &lib_name 'physical path' ;
```

Now that you have your two macro variables you can combine them to generate the dataset reference.  Remember that the macro processor uses period as special character to indicate when the name of the macro variable ends.  So to include the actual period that the SAS language syntax needs between the libref and memname you need to add another period.

```
/* Simple Query */
PROC SQL;
   CREATE TABLE Merged_Contacts AS
      SELECT a.*, b.*
      FROM &lib_name..&table_name 
    ... 
    /*merge another table*/
QUIT;
```